# MSBuild: how to copy multiple build results in different directory

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild

Using Visual Studio Community 2022, i want to build a project for .NET 5.0 et .NET 6.0.

So, the build process create two directories:

- bin\x64\Release\net5.0-windows
- bin\x64\Release\net6.0-windows

I'd like to copy both directories to an other path, so in the build, i add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <BuildDependsOn>$(BuildDependsOn);CustomAfterBuild</BuildDependsOn>
        <_OutputCopyLocationLocal>$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\MyApp\</_OutputCopyLocationLocal>        
        <RunPostBuildEvent>OnBuildSuccess</RunPostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
          <_FilesToCopy Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>        
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(_FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(_OutputCopyLocationLocal)\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

Problem:

In the destination folder, i got a net5.0-windows directory, a net6.0-windows directory and all the contents of net6.0-windows directory.
What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it with a condition on `TargetFramework` (beware of using TargetFramework, not `TargetFrameworks`)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>$(BuildDependsOn);CustomAfterBuild</BuildDependsOn>
    <_OutputCopyLocationLocalNet5>$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\MyApp\net5.0-windows\</_OutputCopyLocationLocalNet5>
    <_OutputCopyLocationLocalNet6>$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\MyApp\net6.0-windows\</_OutputCopyLocationLocalNet6>     
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnBuildSuccess</RunPostBuildEvent>

</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomAfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_FilesToCopy Include="$(OutputPath)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="TargetFramework: $(TargetFramework) " Importance="high" />
    <Message Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-windows'" Text="Starting copy from $(OutputPath) to $(_OutputCopyLocationLocalNet6)" Importance="high" />
    <Copy Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-windows' "
        SourceFiles="@(_FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder = "$(_OutputCopyLocationLocalNet6)\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />        
    <Message Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0-windows'" Text="Starting copy from $(OutputPath) to $(OutputPath) sur $(_OutputCopyLocationLocalNet5)" Importance="high" />
    <Copy Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0-windows' "
        SourceFiles="@(_FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder = "$(_OutputCopyLocationLocalNet5)\%(RecursiveDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />        
</Target>
```